# Can I take my drone to Russia?

Tags: air-travel, drones

I am going to Russia next summer for flthe football World Cup.

I would like to take my drone with me to Russia. I worry that the police or the airport security could confiscate my drone when I enter Russia or when I leave.

Are drones forbidden in Russia?

Answer (score 6):

Drones are [generally allowed](https://www.uavsystemsinternational.com/drone-laws-by-country/russia-drone-laws/) in [Russia](http://www.loc.gov/law/foreign-news/article/russia-simplified-rules-for-drone-operations/).

However they are going to be **prohibited at the World Cup 2018 venues**. If that's the purpose, don't take yours along.

> 5. PROHIBITED ITEMS
>
> ...
>
> 5.1.42. moving and gliding aircraft or their models (gliders, drones, kites, etc.);
>
> ...

Source: [Stadium Code of Conduct for the FIFA Confederations Cup Russia 2017 and
the 2018 FIFA World Cup Russia](https://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/ticketing/02/90/39/62/fwc2018_scc_english-stadiumcodeofconduct_neutral.pdf)

Comment: But if I take the train to get there, is that going to be authorised??

Comment: Not at the venue by any mode of transportation

Comment: To make it simple: Russia - yes; World Cup - no.

Comment: @hisi, On a side-note, border officials and security personnel probably love drones too. They can play with them, resell them, or give them to their own family members. Bringing a drone in, when there is a very clear prohibition rule for the World Cup they can use to confiscate your drone, in my opinion, is just asking for your drone to get confiscated. Also, if your drone is modern enough, it's possible its manufacturer may place GPS restrictions on it for the World Cup the next time you update its firmware.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk the stadium code of conduct can hardly be used to justify confiscation by a border official.  Even with regard to confiscation by security personnel, the code actually calls for prohibited items to be stored in a locker (sections 1.3.6 and 4.1.7).  It can also be inferred that someone refusing to do that should be denied entry into the stadium, not deprived of the item in question.

Comment: @hisi whether drones are allowed on trains is another matter.  I'm unable at the moment to load the website of the Russian rail company, so I can't address the question directly, but you might want to ask a separate question about that, now that you know that you can (in theory at least) bring the drone into Russia.  But there's little point in bringing it if your purpose is to use it at a match.  Doing so will surely lead to trouble, quite likely including its confiscation.

Answer (score 1):

The [code of conduct](https://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/ticketing/02/90/39/62/fwc2018_scc_english-stadiumcodeofconduct_neutral.pdf) states that drones are not allowed in the stadiums, and that makes total sense. From what I gather the normal drone rules apply: do not fly over crowded areas or other restricted areas like the Kremlin and near airports.

[image: Prohibited Items]